# Run powershell command on slave - Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins, master-slave

I'm getting this console output when running a Jenkins job on a slave. The job should create a file and put it in `c:\foo\services.csv`.

Here is the job powershell command:

```
Get-Service | Export-CSV c:\foo\service.csv
```

Note the word “bypass” in this console output. I cannot get past it. I think it is the issue:

> [AnonymousJWTApi] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy
>   ByPass "&
>   'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson1582303083838020200.ps1'"

I found online that the error happens when running a script sitting on a master, on a slave.

So I manually created the script on the slave and put it in `c:\foo\listServices.ps1`. Then in Jenkins (master) this command gets run on the slave: `“C:\foo\listServices.ps1”` to invoke the script to run directly from the slave.

Im still getting the same console output…something about “bypass” seems to be still causing it to not work. The csv file is not being put in the foo folder. Is it the bypass that is preventing it from working, and if so, what is the solution?

And the full console output:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building remotely on slave1 in workspace C:\Jenkins\Master\workspace\AnonymousJWTApi
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url C:\Users\xxx\Source\Repos\AnonymousJWTApi # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from C:\Users\xxx\Source\Repos\AnonymousJWTApi
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress C:\Users\xxx\Source\Repos\AnonymousJWTApi +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 1 remote branch
Checking out Revision a7087f81af855cc96b8763a5ec66b96c19a44a30 (origin/master)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f a7087f81af855cc96b8763a5ec66b96c19a44a30
 > git.exe rev-list a7087f81af855cc96b8763a5ec66b96c19a44a30 # timeout=10
[AnonymousJWTApi] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson1582303083838020200.ps1'"
Finished: SUCCESS
```

**EDIT: The file is getting saved to the master... :P**

It seems the slave is not intended to host the PowerShell scripts or the outputs of them, which I was not aware of.

Comment: Have you logged into the slave and tried to run that command manually?  What happens?

Comment: @ChrisN yes, it works when doing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` ensures that the script file can be run regardless of the execution policy in place for the computer or user. It is correct, and it is not the cause of your issue.

The problem may be permissions.

The Jenkins slave agent is running as a certain user; either the user you used to start it, or if it's running as a service, then it will be the service account.

The user may not have permission to write to `C:\Foo`, so you can check that.

Another way to test this is to write to the workspace directory, so do something like this:

```
Get-Service | Export-CSV $env:WORKSPACE\service.csv
```

That should work. If it does, then change the permission on the `C:\Foo` directory, or run the slave as an account that already has permission.

Here's a way you might be able to tell both which user is running the service, and where the workspace directory is:

```
Get-ChildItem env:\ | Out-String | Set-Content -Path $env:USERPROFILE\env.txt
```

This will write a file called `env.txt` to the profile of the user running the script, containing all of the environment variables (including `%WORKSPACE%`). You'll just have to browse through each user profile to see where it ends up, and then you'll also know the user.

Comment: How do I find out where $env:WORKSPACE is? Running this in powershell on the master it is actually c drive and permission is denied. But on the slave it appears to have worked, I just don't know where to look for the file

Comment: How do you run the slave as an account?

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins you specified the FS root when you defined the slave node on the master; `workspace` will be one level below that, and then I think it will create a folder in there with the name of the job. See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/x/BAN-Ag

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins did you install the slave as a Windows service? If so, you change the account in `services.msc` (the standard Windows services management console) in the properties of the service. If not, then I'm not entirely certain. See if the link in my last comment helps with that.

Comment: It's actually working as expected, I was just thinking the output file would sit on the slave. It goes on the master. Learning a lot from your answer though and it is technically correct as `-ExecutionPolicay Bypass` is not an issue. Cheers

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins if the file is on the master then the job is running on the master, not the slave. You need to restrict where the job can run if you want it to always run on the slave.